# Вывести четные числа в списке

Tags: python

```
a = int(3)
c = float(3.4)
b = int(5)
d = float(4.5)

l = [
    (a + d),
    (c - b),
    (b * c),
    (d / a),
    (a ** 2),
    (a // 2),
    (a % 2)]

print("Список", l)
print("Количество элементов в списке", len(l))

l = input().split()
for i in l:
    if int(i) % 2 == 0:
        print(i)
```

Как правильно вывести четные числа в списке? У мене ничего не выводит...

Comment: зачем у вас `l = input().split()`?

Comment: Скорее всего вы ничего не вводите через input, старый список l перезаписывается пустым списком, в пустом списке нет никаких элементов (ни четных, ни нечетных), поэтому ничего не выводит.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

чтобы получить числа вместо

```
l = input().split()
```

(так вы получаете только список строк)

надо сделать так:

```
l = list(map(int, input().split()))
```

или так:

```
l = [int(obj) for obj in input().split()]
```

список четных чисел можно получить так:

```
arr = [i for i in l if i % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: а у вас зачем `input().split()`?

Comment: @strawdog, а как получить список чисел введенных в одной строке еще как-то?

Comment: а вас не смутило, что товарищ до этого наполнял уже этот список l результатами вычислений? отсюда вопрос - зачем там input?

Comment: а зачем в `l = list(map(int, input().split()))` `input()` как я понял, он для ввода с клавиатуры.

Comment: @Bohdan, да, но вам же числа нужны введенные пользователем? `input()` принимает ввод, `split()` получаем массив слов (разделитель пробел), `map` для каждого элемента этого списка вызывает функцию `int()`, и формирует новый список - т.е. по сути переводит список слов в список целых чисел

Comment: как правильно сделать, что бы не вводить, а использовать уже готовый список 'L'

Comment: @Bohdan, а в чем проблемы - ну замените ввод и формирование списка на существующий список - это же очевидно - заменить `input().split()` на `l`

Answer (score 1):

1. Вы затираете сформированный вами список новым списком, полученным через `input`. Попробуйте ввести числа через пробел и вы увидите результат: `1 2 3 4 5`. Выведутся `2` и `4`.
2. В сформированном вами списке нет чётных чисел, поэтому ничего не выведется из этого списка, если вы закомментируете строку с `input` и используете ваш список из кода.

Вот вывод вашего кода, чётных чисел тут просто нет:

```
Список [7.5, -1.6, 17.0, 1.5, 9, 1, 1]
Количество элементов в списке 7
```